# Android Studio 's xml file @id not work

Tags: android

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relative"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:backgroind="@drawable/ic_launcher" /> 

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

`"android:id"` is not working.

The root view is `work(@+id/relative)`. The TextView prompts `"class' or 'interface' expected"`.
I try other resource(drawable,layout) is ok. only id attr in R file is not work.but root view 's is attr is ok.

I searched google but couldn't find an answer.

help! thank you!

Thank you for answering questions of friends, my first question here, English is not good, thank you very much for your patience:). My previous AndroidStudio version is 0.1.9, is now 0.2.10, make project before the error, you can not run the project, although it is still in the `android: id =" @ + id / ****** "` appear below the red line is not prompted to enter information, but you can make project, you can run the project.

Comment: TextView android:id="@+id/text_view1"  is not work

Comment: RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relative" is work

Comment: are you sure error is in your xml not in your code or other resource files coz `android:id="@+id/text_view1"` looks fine to me

Comment: Littel bit typo here `android:backgroind="@drawable/ic_launcher"`

Answer (score 0):

Try to change to:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:id="@+id/text_view"
    android:backgroind="@drawable/ic_launcher" /> 

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

You need to provide and id for each new control with `@+id`.

Comment: thanks,but it's not work.  textview Prompt "class' or 'interface' expected".

Comment: Does it show which line? Do you have a red cross against a line?

Comment: android:id  line have red @Szymon

Comment: Did you try to clean and rebuild your project?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
   android:id="@+id/text_view" // for textview 1
```

And

```
   android:id="@+id/textview2"  // // for textview 2
```

Any View object may have an integer ID associated with it, to uniquely identify the View within the tree. When the application is compiled, this ID is referenced as an integer, but the ID is typically assigned in the layout XML file as a string, in the id attribute.

Example:

```
android:id="@+id/my_button"
```

The at-symbol (@) at the beginning of the string indicates that the XML parser should parse and expand the rest of the ID string and identify it as an ID resource. The plus-symbol (+) means that this is a new resource name that must be created and added to our resources (in the R.java file).

Check this link. Check the topic under ID

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

Edit:

Also change

```
  android:backgroind="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

to

```
  android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" /> // typo error
```

Comment: @Leon it should how did you try? and pls elaborate not work do you have errors in your resources files?

Comment: errors : "class' or 'interface' expected" . it not prompt "id" after print "@", it prompt "drawable" after print "@". Both "id" and "drawable" have in the R file

Comment: @Leon it should be `@+id`

Comment: @Leon are you sure error is in your xml not in your code or other resource files coz `android:id="@+id/text_view1"` looks fine to me and is right.

Comment: @Leon also you need to change this  `android:backgroind="@drawable/ic_launcher" />` to `android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />` you have a typo error

Answer (score 0):

After following proper conventions and trying Clean/Rebuild multiple times and failing, doing an invalidate caches and restart, solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

It can be defined in `ids.xml` or any custom file like `constants.xml` inside your `res\values` folder.

Examples:

```
<resources>
<item type="id" name="keyboard" />
```

and can be accessed in the code as following:

```
R.id.keyboard
```